# io.sockets.emit error Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

when i start my js script with nodejs, then i get the error:

```html
/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:224
    throw new Error('Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting');
    ^

Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting
    at Namespace.emit (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:224:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:307:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

the part of my script where it happens:

```html
    io.sockets.emit('disconnect', function() {
    var index = -1;
    if(users[user.steamid])
    index = users[user.steamid]['socket'].indexOf(socket.id);
    if (index > -1) {
        users[user.steamid]['socket'].splice(index, 1);
    }
    if(users[user.steamid]) { if(Object.keys(users[user.steamid]['socket']).length == 0) delete users[user.steamid]; }
  });
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong and explain me the error?

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to send `disconnect` event to all sockets (what do you want????). `emit` function only have 2 params (`event_name`, `data`), in your code, you put a function as second param (instead of `data` object).

But, I think your logic is removing a user when detect a socket has been disconnected, hmmm

See here:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var index = -1;
        if (users[user.steamid])
            index = users[user.steamid]['socket'].indexOf(socket.id);
        if (index > -1) {
            users[user.steamid]['socket'].splice(index, 1);
        }
        if (users[user.steamid]) { if (Object.keys(users[user.steamid]['socket']).length == 0) delete users[user.steamid]; }
    });
});
```